# I want to draw a transition in automata exactly as shown below. From state q7 to state q1

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, circuitikz, automata

[image: I have made this automata. But i cannot make this single line exact same way and I am totally frustrated]

[image: image to be made. I want exact same line but i can't fix it]

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[landscape, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem,amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,positioning,shapes}
\usepackage{amstext}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170.00 mm,257.00 mm},
    left=20.00 mm,
    top=20.00 mm,
}
\begin{document}

    \textbf{Modify the following PDA so  that an equivalent CFG can be obtained.\\}
    \newline\newline

    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=4.1cm,
    thick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=gray,text=white]

    \node[initial above,state] (q1)              {$q_{1}$};
    \node[state]         (q2)  [below  left=2.5cm and 3.25cm of q1]{$q_{2}$};

    \node[state]         (q3) [below  right=2.5cm and 3.25cm of q1] {$q_{3}$};
    \node[state]         (q4) [below =2cm of q2] {$q_{4}$};
    \node[state]         (q5) [below =2cm of q3] {$q_{5}$};

    \node[state]         (q6) [below right=2.5cm and 3.25cm of q4] {$q_{6}$};



    \node[state]         (q7) [below= 1.5cm of q6] {$q_{7}$};

    \node[state]         (q8) [below= 2.5 of q1] {$q_{8}$};

    \node[state]         (qaccept) [below=6cm =q8] {$_{qaccept}$};

    \path[->] 

    (q1) edge node[sloped,align=center, anchor=center, above, text width=2.0cm] {0 $\rightarrow$ x , R} (q2)

    (q1) edge node[sloped,align=center, anchor=center, above, text width=2.0cm] {\# $\rightarrow$ R} (q8)

    (q8) edge node[sloped,align=center, anchor=center, above, text width=2.0cm] {u $\rightarrow$ R} (qaccept)

    (q1) edge node[sloped,align=center, anchor=center, above, text width=2.0cm] {1 $\rightarrow$ x , R} (q3)


    (q2) edge node[align=center,left] {\# $\rightarrow$ R} (q4)

    (q3) edge node[align=center,right] {\# $\rightarrow$ R} (q5)

    (q4) edge node[align=center,sloped, anchor=center, below, text width=2.0cm] {0$\rightarrow$x , L} (q6)

    (q5) edge node[align=center,sloped, anchor=center, below, text width=2.0cm] {1$\rightarrow$x , L} (q6)

    (q6) edge node {\# $\rightarrow$ L} (q7)

    (q2) edge [align=center,loop left] node {0,1 $\rightarrow$ R} (q2)
    (q3) edge [align=center,loop right] node {0,1 $\rightarrow$ R} (q3)
    (q4) edge [align=center,loop left] node {x $\rightarrow$ R} (q4)
    (q5) edge [align=center,loop right] node {x $\rightarrow$ R} (q5)
    (q6) edge [align=center,loop right] node {0,1,x $\rightarrow$ L} (q6)
    (q7) edge [align=center,loop right] node {0,1 $\rightarrow$ L} (q7)
    (q8) edge [align=center,loop right] node {x $\rightarrow$ R} (q8)

    ;

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please specify what exactly is your question? Adding the arrow from `q1` to `q7`?

Comment: Welcome to our site. Instead of writing that you are frustrated, you should give us a hint on where exactly your problems are. Like this we do not have to compare pictures in order to find the issue. Please try to make your code as minimal as possible.

Comment: Yes i want to add an arrow from q7 to q1.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I am trying this transition since 4 hours.
I believe there are little redundant lines of code. every line is responsible to create either a node or a transition. 
I want to make a transition from q7 to q1 as shown in a figure 2.

Comment: @samcarter 
I have updated the question. Yes I want transition from q7 to q1 as in figure 2

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I've deleted the comments in the code. 
Yes I'm sorry for not explaining my problem. 
I have updated the question. Yes I want transition from q7 to q1 as in figure 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[landscape,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170.00 mm,257.00 mm},
    left=20.00 mm,
    top=20.00 mm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    ,->
    ,>=stealth'
    ,shorten >=1pt
    ,node distance=4.1cm
    ,thick
    ,auto
    ,state/.append style={fill=gray,text=white}
    ]
    \node[initial above,state] (q1)              {$q_{1}$};
    \node[state]         (q2)  [below  left=2.5cm and 3.25cm of q1]{$q_{2}$};   
    \node[state]         (q3) [below  right=2.5cm and 3.25cm of q1] {$q_{3}$};
    \node[state]         (q4) [below =2cm of q2] {$q_{4}$};
    \node[state]         (q5) [below =2cm of q3] {$q_{5}$}; 
    \node[state]         (q6) [below right=2.5cm and 3.25cm of q4] {$q_{6}$};   
    \node[state]         (q7) [below= 1.5cm of q6] {$q_{7}$};   
    \node[state]         (q8) [below= 2.5 of q1] {$q_{8}$}; 
    \node[state]         (qaccept) [below=6cm =q8] {$q_\text{accept}$};

    \path   
    (q1) edge node[sloped,align=center, anchor=center, above, text width=2.0cm] {0 $\rightarrow$ x , R} (q2)    
    (q1) edge node[sloped,align=center, anchor=center, above, text width=2.0cm] {\# $\rightarrow$ R} (q8)   
    (q8) edge node[sloped,align=center, anchor=center, above, text width=2.0cm] {u $\rightarrow$ R} (qaccept)   
    (q1) edge node[sloped,align=center, anchor=center, above, text width=2.0cm] {1 $\rightarrow$ x , R} (q3)    
    (q2) edge node[align=center,left] {\# $\rightarrow$ R} (q4) 
    (q3) edge node[align=center,right] {\# $\rightarrow$ R} (q5)    
    (q4) edge node[align=center,sloped, anchor=center, below, text width=2.0cm] {0$\rightarrow$x , L} (q6)  
    (q5) edge node[align=center,sloped, anchor=center, below, text width=2.0cm] {1$\rightarrow$x , L} (q6)  
    (q6) edge node {\# $\rightarrow$ L} (q7)    
    (q2) edge [align=center,loop left] node {0,1 $\rightarrow$ R} (q2)
    (q3) edge [align=center,loop right] node {0,1 $\rightarrow$ R} (q3)
    (q4) edge [align=center,loop left] node {x $\rightarrow$ R} (q4)
    (q5) edge [align=center,loop right] node {x $\rightarrow$ R} (q5)
    (q6) edge [align=center,loop right] node {0,1,x $\rightarrow$ L} (q6)
    (q7) edge [align=center,loop right] node {0,1 $\rightarrow$ L} (q7)
    (q8) edge [align=center,loop right] node {x $\rightarrow$ R} (q8);
    \draw [rounded corners=20](q7.west) -- ++(-6.7,0) node[pos=.4,above]{x $\rightarrow$ R} |- (q1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! You're God sent angel :) Thank you so much :)

Comment: @MuhammadAliShahzad You are welcome!